# Specific question on improving LUIS speech recognition

Tags: azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am just testing LUIS with intents and entities and have a couple of things I need to fix.

When I say the word "patent" it was recognized as "patern" how can I improve this?

I am attempting to recognize individual letters for example a b c etc.  I am Australian and so I say for "z" zed and not zzzzz (US).  I set the [SpeechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.speechconfig.speechrecognitionlanguage?view=azure-dotnet) to "en-AU", however when I say my "z" the recognized text is "zed". If I say zzzz the recognized text is correct with z.

When i say the number five four eight nine it is recognized as "five 489" I am expecting "5489".  I have an entity pattern regex of [0-9]{4} as I want to know when a 4 digit number is spoken, however this does not work when it recognizes "five 489" how am I supposed to fix this?

I want to be able to distinguish between "show me record 12345" and "show me the record".  How should I do this? Should I have different Intents or should I have 1 intent but look for 1 with an entity of 12345 and one without?

Comment: you can post your question specific to speech recognition on https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues and the LUIS team will look into it